# Sending data across Components while hiding url params

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is it possible to transfer data using router-link but to not display the data in the url.

```
 Component1.vue 
<template>
<router-link :to="{name: 'components2', params: {name: 
this name, age: this.age}}">Go to Components 2
</router-link>
</template>
```

Comment: I don't think that will be possible. Any reason why you want the data hidden?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb: When passing data around IN BROWSER it is impossible to hide it directly and security through obfuscation is a futile approach, too. Perhaps rethink the level of security you need on these pages and consider offloading it into a stateful management system serverside you can reference in `beforeRouteEnter`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Sometimes, only trivial changes should be prevented. E.g. Preventing a user to change the item ID in the URL, because the UI is not made for user changes to the URL. The back-end, of course, would then prevent the change (no security impact).

Comment: @OhgodWhy Discovered it was actually pointless, had to rethink the logic, Vuex was helpful.